# How do I import this project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried downloading and importing this the conventional way, but it doesn't work after I do this. Could someone tell me where I am wrong?

The link: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/teach-your-next-android-app-to-speak/
(I tried downloading the whole project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**File** > click on **Import...**.

[image: This]

Then click on **Existing Android Code Into Workspace**

[image: is]

Then click on **Browse...** and click on the project you downloaded and click ok.

[image: it]

Comment: I did this, just wondering whether I import the whole project or only the source code?

Comment: Whole project. As the source code is just a java code which won't be able to combine the `xml` file i.e the main view of an android application containing all the components.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this way

**Import > Android > Existing Android code into workspace > your_project folder > finish**

Answer (score 0):

### *After Downloading project* ::

**Step1**: Download the project and `unzip` it

**Step2**: Go to eclipse editor -> `File` -> `Import` -> `Android` -> `Existing code into android workspace`

**Step3**: Find the place where you unzipped your project which you downloaded

**Step4**: Click -> `Open`

*This should impost the entire project to youe workspace*

### **[Check this video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IYnkIre1sA)**

***Let me know if you come across any difficulties*** !